# Interpretation of fourier transform of an array of delta functions

Tags: fourier-analysis

I evaluated the Fourier series of $\delta(x-nd)$ for integer n between infinity and minus infinity I think this is an expression for an infinite array of delta functions separated by d. When I evaluated the Fourier transform into q space (reciprocal partner to x) I got $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty exp(-iq(nd))$ which is also $1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty cos(ndq)$. I've been told that the Fourier transform should be an array of delta functions separated 1/d but I can't see how either of these expressions can geometrically represent that array.

Comment: [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) for some references.

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514258/intuition-behind-alternate-expression-of-impulse-train/1514413#1514413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the similar post:

just play with this [interactive Desmos Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/erjj08ecii) and see.
The point is *constructive and destructive interferences* : every cos contributes around the Dirac comb support or progressively cancel each other at other places, resulting into the Dirac comb.

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of dirac delta functions is $\frac 1{2\pi}   \int_{-∞}^∞ {e^{iw(t-t_0)}}dw)$

Then going back to your questions what you derived is some function f(q) = $\sum_{n=-∞}^∞ exp^{-iqnd}$

which is equivalent

is equivalent to $\sum_{n=-∞}^∞ \Bigl( \int_{-∞}^∞ \bigl( {e^{(\frac{x_0}{nd}-x)iq}}\bigr)^{nd} dx \Bigr)$, in which we have multiple Dirac functions separated by distance nd and of amplitude nd.

...